# LoadTesting in Jmeter

Tags: selenium, junit, automation, jmeter

I wrote test case using selenium webdrive. also i use junit.
Now i want to test that test case for 100 + users.

So i use treads in that application, but i can go up to that much of users because my memory in not enough for that(open 100+ browsers).

So is there a way to test this in Jmeter.

I can't use badboy recording and import it to Jmeter because somehow my application doesn't support it. (the replay doesn't work in badboay).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JMeter offers it's own recording solution - [HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder). You can record your test case with it and then try to replay.

If you need to check only unauthenticated navigation, like accessing different pages by anonymous user it should work as a charm. However if you test assumes authentication (log in), creating or updating some stuff, etc. you may need to use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to deal with user authentication and [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post Processor to fetch dynamic values from responses and add them to next request.

There are some more components you may wish to consider adding to make your test look like more realistic:

1. Add HTTP Header Manager - to set different headers like User-Agent, Accept-Language, etc. - what real browser does
2. Add HTTP Cache Manager - to simulate browser cache
3. Make sure that "Retrieve all embedded resources" property of HTTP Sampler is checked - to simulate parsing css, images, scripts, etc.
4. Make sure that "Use concurrent pool" is enabled and has size from 2 to 5 threads - as browsers download embedded stuff asynchronously in several threads
5. Make sure that you filter out external domains in "URLs must match" field - you unlikely want to load test Google Analytics or external banners or whatever